# Detected Vetur enabled. Consider disabling Vetur and use @volar-plugins/vetur instead

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, vetur, volar

VSCode is giving the following warning

> Detected Vetur enabled. Consider disabling Vetur and use
> `@volar-plugins/vetur` instead.

What is this for? What do I need to do to turn it off

Answer (score 16, accepted):

TLDR: uninstall Vetur and keep Volar (official recommended extension).

---

Volar is the official VScode plugin to use since few months, hence why the core team is pushing the officially supported one.
It was initially meant for Vue3 but it also works with Vue2.

As explained here: https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/overview.html#ide-support

Also this github issue: https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/issues/3476#issue-1300202219

---

Official page of the project btw

[image]

Comment: @user3953989 un-install Vetur and install Volar. Volar is the one to use today. As for why: there is no official support for Vetur anymore, the focus is now ported on Volar since it is more powerful, better written, and adapted towards Vue3. Please read the given links for more details.

Comment: In case you want to have a little help: I have created an extension which will check if the "unwanted" extensions are disabled in the current workspace or not. This can help if you work with other developers on the same project, and make sure they have specific extensions disabled. Note: As of now this is not yet fully automatable, so the user needs to be guided: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GARAIOAG.garaio-vscode-unwanted-recommendations

Answer (score 3):

In your VScode extensions, find 'Vetur' and Disable. Reload VScode

or you can use 'Vetur' in another way @volar-plugins/vetur.

Answer (score 2):

disable the plugin vetur by Pine wu, or uinstall it.
just keep volar